# Running optimize-js after Uglify in Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

**Using Webpack 4, how can I run [`optimize-js`](https://github.com/nolanlawson/optimize-js) after Webpack runs Uglify?**

It seems that in earlier versions of Webpack, you would use a plugin like [`optimize-js-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimize-js-plugin). I couldn't get this to work as Webpack appears to apply plugins before minifying code, so the `optimize-js` transformation is lost when Uglify minifies.

I tried setting `optimization.minimizer` to `[]` in my Webpack config, which disabled the built-in minification, but when I added `UglifyjsWebpackPlugin` to my plugins, it didn't seem to do anything and I got unminified sources.

Thoughts?

My additional requirement is that I need to preserve source maps through all the transformations so I can map from the post-Optimize, post-Uglify sources back to the original TypeScript sources (so I can get resolve crash stacks into something meaningful).

My next route would be to just write a script that calls `optimize-js` via the Node APIs and then use `source-map-merger` (or similar) to preserve the source maps. The downside would be that a script like this would run outside of Webpack and I somehow have to identify all the webpack outputs. Fairly straightforward, but not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried defining both plugins as minimizers, in the order you want them to be applied:

```
optimization.minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({...}),
    new OptimizeJsPlugin({...})
]
```